# Axioms of Combinatorics

Tags: combinatorics, axioms

What are the axioms of Combinatorics? Does it have a set of well-defined axioms? Because most Combinatorial solutions are not formulated in a mathematical manner (at least those I have seen) and contain a considerable portion of natural language and mostly refer to "obvious" things. Is Combinatorics axiom-less or every Combinatorial solution is a logical conclusion of axioms?

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4276732/820922

Comment: This is tough to answer. There is a sense in which the axioms of combinatorics can be (a portion of) your favorite set theory axioms, and it doesn't matter which set theory you pick.

Comment: I think you might mean to instead ask a question that's not about axioms at all, but instead something like "how can informal combinatorial arguments like [insert links to specific examples] be made rigorous?". (Informal arguments exist in all fields of math, so if this is what you mean, the links to or text of examples of the sort of thing you have in mind will be crucial.)

Comment: "The basic problem of [Enumerative Combinatorics](https://math.mit.edu/~rstan/ec/) is that of counting the number
of elements of a finite set." Thus, the basic properties of numbers and sets are presupposed.

Answer (score 1):

There are some principles in combinatorics, like

equality principle (sets for which there is a bijection between them have the same cardinality).

addition principle: $|\bigcup_i A_i| = \sum_i |A_i|$ for sets which are pairwise disjoint.

multiplication principle: $|\prod_i A_i|  = \prod_i |A_i|$.