# Axiomatic books for combinatorics and number theory

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory, reference-request

I would like to know if there are any books on combinatorics and number theory that follow an axiomatic approach akin to that of Sierpinski's General Topology. I have found some books for both subjects that might follow this axiomatic approach but they aren't explicit about it. The books I am referring to are:

Aigner's Combinatorial Theory, which one user on Amazon said follows an algebraic approach but I don't know if that is equivalent to an axiomatic approach.

Landau's Elementary Number Theory, with the author having written an axiomatic book on Analysis called Foundations of Analysis, which I have a suspicion might be axiomatic.

And Sierpinski's Elementary Theory of Numbers by the author I mentioned above with my suspicion being that it also follows an axiomatic approach.

I have scoured the internet for such books but to no avail. I haven't found posts on stack exchange that address this question, specifically for number theory and combinatorics, either so I decided to write one myself. I really hope someone here might have found such books.

More specifically Brualdi's book on combinatorics states that the multiplication principle is a consequence of the addition principle while Vinogradov's number theory book states that division with remainder is a generalization of the quotient of two integers. I would like the books to follow such an approach, stating what is essential and deriving everything else logically. I don't think I can be any more specific but I hope you get the gist of what I am saying.

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4338204/axioms-of-combinatorics

Comment: Typically combinatorics and number theory are built on top of standard set theory (presumably the same axioms for set theory that are in Sierpinski's book, I've never read it). So if you understand sets, functions, an axiomatic construction of the integers and rationals, etc., all of which would be in any intro set theory book, then I'm not sure what else you would be looking for in combinatorics and number theory specifically. More details in your question on what exactly you want from the book might be helpful.